# LastIndexof inside my foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following code inside my asp.net mvc web application :-

```
foreach (var i in switchtags)
{
    result = result + i + " ; ";
}
```

but I want to check if the `i` variable is the last inside the `switchtags` to prevent concatenating a `;` after it something such as :-

```
foreach (var i in switchtags)
{
    if(i.LastIndexOf())
        result = result + i ;
    else
    {
        result = result + i + " ; ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not allow it and then `TrimEnd(';');`?

Comment: `string.Join(" ; ", switchtags)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like:

```
var finalResult = string.Join(";", switchtags);
```

Alternatively, if you want to use your current loop then use

```
result = result.TrimEnd(';');
```

Answer (score 1):

It'd be much easier to use `string.Join`:

```
string result = string.Join(";", switchtags);
```

Answer (score 1):

`String.Join` is the best way for you do to it.

```
result = String.Join(";", switchtags)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string.Join(",", listOfString)
```

This works well for this problem.